# Coqc mangles filenames

Tags: coq

Whenever I call `coqc A` or `coqc A.v` from the terminal, I get the error `Error: Can't find file A.v.v on loadpath` (note the double .v.v). This is on a fresh installation of Coq 8.6 via Opam on Mac OS (I've previously used 8.4 and 8.5 without trouble).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you double-checked that you have installed 8.6 and *not* the development version?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like I was making a mistake by adding

`export PATH="~/opam-coq.8.6/4.01.0/bin/:$PATH"`

to my bash_profile.

Something of the form 
`. [OPAMDIR]/opam-init/init.sh > /dev/null 2> /dev/null || true` 
is recommended, but I have no init.sh file.

The following worked however:

`export OPAMROOT=~/opam-coq.8.6`

`` eval `opam config env` ``